# Can I use `inout` with protocol extensions?

Tags: swift

I have a protocol and its extension, and a class conforming to the protocol.

```
protocol WarAbilities {
    var strength: Int { get set }
    func attack(inout opponent: WarAbilities)
}

extension WarAbilities {
    func attack(inout opponent: WarAbilities) {
        opponent.strength -= 1
    }
}

class Warrior: WarAbilities {
    var strength: Int

    init(strength: Int) {
        self.strength = strength
    }
}
```

Now if I want to make two warriors fight:

```
let thug1 = Warrior(strength: 10)
let thug2 = Warrior(strength: 30)

thug1.attack(&thug2)
```

I get this error message:

> error: cannot pass immutable value of type 'WarAbilities' as inout argument

Adding `mutating` looked promising:

```
protocol WarAbilities {
    var strength: Int { get set }
    mutating func attack(inout opponent: WarAbilities)
}

extension WarAbilities {
    mutating func attack(inout opponent: WarAbilities) {
        opponent.strength -= 1
    }
}
```

But the compiler isn't happy either and I fail to understand what the new error message means:

> error: cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: implicit conversion from 'Warrior' to 'WarAbilities' requires a temporary

Since `Warrior` conforms to `WarAbilities` I thought one of those would work - but it looks like Swift doesn't have this kind of... covariance? I'm not even sure what I'm talking about here.

**What's my mistake?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make it a `class` protocol and get rid of the (then) unnecessary `inout` stuff:

```
protocol WarAbilities : class {
    var strength: Int { get set }
    func attack(opponent: WarAbilities)
}

extension WarAbilities {
    func attack(opponent: WarAbilities) {
        opponent.strength -= 1
    }
}

class Warrior: WarAbilities {
    var strength: Int

    init(strength: Int) {
        self.strength = strength
    }
}

let thug1 = Warrior(strength: 10)
let thug2 = Warrior(strength: 30)

thug1.attack(thug2)

thug2.strength // 29
```

(Indeed it's rather unclear to me why you need a protocol here at all; since Warrior is a class, you can just make WarAbilities its superclass.)

Answer (score 2):

Two things are wrong in my opinion:

1. passing a `let`-constant to `inout`
2. passing a subtype as `inout`

<s>Note that in your example you do not even *need* `inout` since you do not overwrite the parameter, but *some* instance member of that parameter. Simply dropping the `inout` will probably work in your case since you do not need it at all.</s> (see matt's answer for proper dealing with this issue)

Note secondly that using `mutating` probably is not going to do you any good here since that only is talking about mutating its own members, not the members of the parameters.

---

**Explanation of the problem:**
Lets consider the far simpler problem which produces the exact same problem output:

```
protocol A {}
class B : A {}

func c(inout d : A) {}

let a = B()
c(&a)
```

That firstly does not work because `a` is a constant. Therefore change the `let` to `var`.
Then the compiler complains about requiring a temporary. That is a quite confusing error message but the problem actually makes sense.

**You cannot pass a subtype of some Type to an `inout`**  or an implementation of some protocol to an `inout` expecting the protocol

Explanation - consider the following example:

```
class A {}
class B : A {}

func c(inout a : A) { a = A() }
```

What should happen if you call that method via

```
var b = B()
c(&b)
```

`b` would be changed and it would now be the same as `a` - but `a` is not of type `B` which `b` is said to be.

Note that the following will work again:

```
var b : A = B()
c(&b)
```

We pass in a `B` but actually only worry about it being an `A`. Same goes for protocols:

```
protocol P {}
class K : P {}
class X : P {}

func f(inout p : P) { p = X() }

var k = K()
f(&k) // does not work

var p : P = K()
f(&p) // works
```

Comment: "Note that in your example you do not even need inout since you do not overwrite the parameter" You're wrong about that. He's trying to change a property of the instance passed as argument. Without `inout`, he can't do that if this is a struct parameter. That's why in my answer I make this a `class` protocol — so the compiler knows this is _not_ a struct parameter.

Comment: @matt `inout` does not care about the parameter being a struct or class, it cares about being constant or not. passing in a struct works the exact same way. Using a class-only protocol only removes the underlying problem of mutating a struct. But that has nothing to do with the `inout` - you are certainly allowed to *overwrite* a struct passed as `inout`.

Comment: @matt after reading your comment again I have to agree you are partially correct about the necessity of the `inout`. So the first minor part of my answer is incorrect, yes. Luckily it does not change the remaining arguments and reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

**Inout with protocol support:**

```
protocol IPositional{
    func setPosition(position:CGPoint)
}
extension IPositional{
    var positional:IPositional {get{return self as IPositional}set{}}
}
class A:IPositional{
    var position:CGPoint = CGPoint()
    func setPosition(position:CGPoint){
        self.position = position
    }
}
func test(inout positional:IPositional){
    positional.setPosition(CGPointMake(10,10))
}
var a = A()
test(&a.positional)
a.position//(10.0, 10.0)
```

**Conclusion:**
The benefit of doing it this way: Is that you can now have one "inout method" for all classes that implements IPositional